# Can you prove an eigenvector is 1 if an eigenvalue is 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a symmetric 5x5 matrix of rank 4 and determinant 0 and one eigenvalue ($\lambda$<sub>n</sub>) = 0.

**Without direct calculation**, how do you prove that the eigenvector for the zero eigenvalue is **1**?

I.e. Is there a proof that lets you **inspect** the matrix or its row echelon form and come to this conclusion without directly calculating the eigenvector?

I am sure it is related to (A - I$\lambda$)**x** = **0** - but I am still getting my head around all these "*eigenthings*" and have confused myself.

The row echelon form of the 5x5 matrix is:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
-1 & 4 & -1 & -1 & -1\\
0 & -1 & -1 & 3 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -21 & 21 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$

Comment: My guess is that that $4$ from the third row is a $-4$. Otherwise, $\mathbf 1$ will not be an eigenvector.

Comment: Thanks - fixed it. So if it is -4, what tells you there is a 1 eigenvector?

Comment: Your original statement is stated for a rather general matrix $A$ and your Row Echelon Form is superfluous. Its very use seems counter the **without direct calculation** directive. Indeed, the fact that the row sums are all zero follows from your observation that $(A-\lambda I)\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ for the value $\lambda=0$ and the very definition of matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you sum the entries of each row, you get $0$. This is the same thing as asserting that$$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 4 & -1 & -1 & -1\\0 & -1 & -1 & 3 & -1\\0 & 0 & 1 & -4 & 3 \\0 & 0 & 0 & -21 & 21 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=0\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$In other words, $\mathbf 1$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Oh - I see. I have been doing that multiplication with A - which the rows do not sum to zero. So doing this with A in row-echelon form is okay then?

Comment: What is ref(A)?

Comment: row-echelon form. (I updated my comment to remove the ambiguity sorry)

Comment: In general, it is not okay. There is not connection between the eigenvectors of a matrix $A$ and the eigenvectors of the matrix that you get after putting $A$ in row-echelon form. But it is true for *any* square matrix that $\mathbf1$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $0$ if and only if the sums of the entries of all rows are $0$.

Comment: Thanks. So just to confirm - because it is a square matrix, the fact there is an eigenvector of 1 in the row-echelon form, there will be an eigenvector of 1 in the original matrix A. Have I got it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, although it does not follow from anything that I wrote above.

Comment: Thanks again. I would like to understand this more. What is the proof/rule that makes that a true statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130121/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-bryon).

Comment: Thank you Jose! I didn't notice in the original question that the rows of matrix A sum to zero. So now it all makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do it **without direct calculation**? Indeed, doing so obscures the generality of the result.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I assumed that what the OP had in mind by that was, after knowing that $0$ is an eigenvalue, to determine a corresponding eigenvector through direct calculation.

Comment: Yes. The problem was “given you know there is a zero eigenvector show there is a 1 vector without direct calculation”. My guess it was about getting people to analyse the matrix and learn about recognising characteristics and draw conclusions without always having to go through the math (which would have been my default position). It worked. I learned a ton!